# add number to event button after click in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need help with this simple task. I have button that after click it add another `li` element "item X". x=follow number

```
<ul id="list">
<li>item 0</li>
</ul>
<button id="addElem">Add</button>
```

```
var flag = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < flag.length; i++) {}
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var add = document.getElementById('addElem');
add.addEventListener('click', function() {
var NewlistElem = document.createElement('li');
list.appendChild(NewlistElem).innerHTML += 'item' + flag[i];
})
```

Comment: forgot to add:<body>
    <ul id="list">
        <li>item 0</li>
    </ul>
    <button id="addElem">
  Add
</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var flag = document.getElementsByTagName('li'); // #1
flag=flag[flag.length-1].innerHTML; // #2
flag=parseInt(flag.match(/\d+/))+1; // #3
```

Explanation

- `#1` -> get all li elements
- `#2` -> select last li element's innerHTML
- `#3` -> using regexp, get the number in and convert into Int using `parseInt` and add + 1

```js
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var add = document.getElementById('addElem');
add.addEventListener('click', function() {
var flag = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
flag=flag[flag.length-1].innerHTML;
flag=parseInt(flag.match(/\d+/))+1;
var NewlistElem = document.createElement('li');
list.appendChild(NewlistElem).innerHTML += 'item' + flag;
})
```

```html
<ul id="list">
<li>item 0</li>
</ul>
<button id="addElem">Add</button>
```

Comment: thank u so much u have no idea how log i struggled. mannyy thanks:D

Comment: Anytime. also marking as answers will help future visitors.